# Why am I getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

i have an array of boolean type 
which is

```
static boolean[][] a = new boolean[50][50];
```

everytime gets input, 
it marks the specified array as true
that is,

```
for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
  int x=sc.nextInt();
  int y=sc.nextInt();
  a[x][y] = true;
}
```

but when the number of input, depending on k, gets large,
the following error comes out

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

what is wrong with this

Comment: Please rephrase your question title. :)

Comment: @Everton, fixed that for you :)

Comment: surprised to see 10 answers on a crude/incomplete question( moreover the asker is not showing any response ), with many up-votes on answers and people still posting answers in the hope of up-votes including many 10k+ reputation people, while other questions in SO are still unanswered ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Exception` you see is because you're trying to access an element of the array that doesn't exist (Lies Outside the Bounds).

The array you initialize has elements 0...49 in both dimensions. So you can insert values into any position that lies within a[0-49][0-49]

When you do:

```
int x=sc.nextInt();
int y=sc.nextInt();
a[x][y] = true;
```

There's the possibliity that you access a value beyond those locations. Such as a negative value or a too high one (In this case you're accessing -1).

Your issue stems from the fact that `sc.nextInt()` is failing to produce a usable integer from your input. How are you initializing `sc`?

Answer (score 3):

It means that you've tried to access element an element with index `-1` in the array. So `nextInt()` returned -1 somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

A `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptio` means you tried to access an illegal index within the array.

i.e. `index < 0` or `index >= array.length`

In this instance, the index was `-1`.

In your 2 dimensional array, at some point, either `x` or `y` is pointing to an illegal point in the top array or the nested array.

To fix it, you could ensure `x` and `y` is always withing range (arguably a bandaid) or fix `sc.nextInt()` to return valid values.

```
for (int i=0; i<k; i++) {
    int x=sc.nextInt();
    int y=sc.nextInt();
    if (x<0 || x>=a.length) continue;
    if (y<0 || y>=a[x].length) continue;
    a[x][y] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try printing x and y before `a[x][y] = true;` x or y may be -1

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
  int x=sc.nextInt();
  int y=sc.nextInt();
if(x >0 && y>0 && x<a.length && y <a[x].length)
  a[x][y] = true;
}
```

Comment: The source of the problem is the input, not how it's being handled. In this case, the scanner should avoid values outside of the array's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

`x` or `y` is -1 ant this is invalid array index (your arrays are indexed from 0 to 49).

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Says that you are trying to access index = -1, array index starts from 0

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is that either x or y is >= 50 in `a[x][y] = true` (or lower than 0). You've got to make sure that x and y are at least 0 and at last 49.

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing the array beyond [50][50] index. Try specifying a boundary in the nextInts to keep the indexes within range: `int x = sc.nextInt(49); int y = sc.nextInt(49);`

Answer (score 0):

Your Scanner reads values for x and y, and if one of these are outside of the array's bounds (in this case less than 0 and greater than 49), you'll get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.